# Need a 8x8 permutation matrix

Tags: java, matrix

**SHORT STORY :**

I need a `8x8` matrix, that can have many solutions (a 
well known existing problem)
Solutions as in, it should have only `8` positions which are `1`, rest `0`.

A good example can be `8 queen problem`.(Placing 8 queens in such a way that they don't kill each other)

[Queen problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle)

so we can create a matrix, which will have 64 positions in all,and `1` represents the current queen position, and `0` a blank position.

**LONG STORY:**

I am creating an algorithm for [Steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) which needs a 8x8 matrix(`say A`) to store the pixels of an image(8 pixels at a time,8 bits each).

Another `8x8` matrix `say B`, is to be created which contains data such that Only 8 places should have a 1,rest 0.

These bits are then collectively mapped to matrix `A`, to check and evaluate an 8 bit resultant 
ASCII valued string.

So, I can make many combinations like that, say combinations of 8 kings on a `8x8` chessboard so that the don't kill each other.But it's not a well known,or a tricky problem.

Any ideas for creating such a matrix? The idea can be from anywhere, not generally related to a chessboard.

Comment: Kindly please explain your reasons for down-voting.Thank you.@downvoter

Comment: Nice story(ies). But, where is your attempt? Also, what language should this be in?

Comment: @jrd1 Language is not a bar here.Matrix _is_ a matrix.Idea is more important.

Comment: Still edited the tags,@jrd1

Comment: I did not get the problem. You just want a permutation matrix or does it have to conform to some other requirements as well?

Comment: @Henry no other requirements.Just a permutation matrix, but well known      idea,for example 8 queens problem, as I stated.

Comment: Will be back with an edit.

Comment: Please vote to close, i'll come up with some code.

Answer (score 1):

- Consider the 8x8 fields as the adjacency matrix of a graph with 8 nodes and 8 edges
- Enumerate all these graphs
- Find "interesting" properties of these graphs.

  - Example: "Has a chromatic number of 3"
  - Example: "Contains at least / at most / exactly `A` nodes with degree `B`"
  - ...
- Profit

Comment: hmm interesting.I'll work on it and let you know.But still,  will I get many combinations? I mean around 100?

Answer (score 0):

One way to proceed is to start with a unit matrix (i.e. 1 entries only in the main diagonal and 0 entries elsewhere) and to randomly shuffle the rows.

Comment: I need a well known problem :)

Comment: Can you define "well known" in a precise way? In some sense every permutation is well known.

Comment: Have you seen a link to 8 queen problem I have given in my question?

Comment: Yes, so you want one of the 92 solutions of that problem? That's why I asked if there are additional constraints.

Comment: All the 92 solutions.like : solutions [8][8][192],so something similar  stuff

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not going into detail about the problem itself, I guess what you are asking for is a data structure to accommodate the matrix, and not the algorithm to solve the problem.

A valid datastructure would be a two-dimensional array `int[8][8]` or even `boolean[8][8]`, since you only need two states per field.

If you're asking for a datastructure that verifies the rule of not more or less than eight marked fields, you can implement a wrapper class around such array that contain the logic to validate.

I might have grossly misunderstood you though.